# ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS sudo apt-get update

Tags: package-management, beagleboard

I'm currently running ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on a Beagle Bone Black (BBB.) I decided to use this distribution on the BBB as I was having issues installing packages(such as minicom) on the supported Debian distribution.

When I try to update ubuntu using the command **sudo apt-get update** I receive this error.

```
Err:1 http://repos.rcn-ee.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease   Temporary failure resolving 'repos.rcn-ee.com' 
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic InRelease                           Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com' 
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise InRelease                 Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com' 
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-updates InRelease   Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com' 
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease   Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com' Reading package lists... Done
```

---

***NOTE: I have had to remove the rest of the error code due to stackoverflow rules. I will respond with the rest of the error message in the comments below.***

- I have updated the /etc/apt/sources.list file.
  What can I do in order to resolve this issue ? Am I having due to the ubuntu version I am currently using ?

Comment: What Stack Exchange rule meant you couldn't add the error? If it is too long, please don't put it in the comments. Instead, you can use [the Ubuntu pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/). Better yet, you can [edit] your question to only include the relevant parts of the error. Also, what are you trying to do? Update to 18.04? 14.04.4 LTS isn't Debian, it is Ubuntu. It also is not supported (and is off-topic).

Comment: there is a mix of sources.  Save your data and install a supported release.

Comment: Removed the confusing 14.04 tag.

Comment: Check network connectivity first. All sites from your question are alive. What is your actual Ubuntu release on this board?

Comment: the problem is either with your network having a faulty DNS server configuration or the DNS server you have configured isn't up. The `Temporary failure resolving...` bit in the error messages indicates that the problem is a network config issue and has nothing to do with `apt-get`. Are you getting any internet connection on the device?

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/    Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) is also EOL; but your post is confusing as they mentions 12.04, 14.04 & 18.04? Ports & Archives?

Comment: @cocomac Originally I was using the official debian image for the BBB I changed to ubuntu even though it isn't a supported distribution.  I am using ubuntu 18.04 on my BBB, currently.

Comment: @N0rbert My issue was connectivity. Thanks

Comment: @guiverc I will make sure to use supported versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue.
Checking Network connectivity.